# How to install sqlplus in macOS M1 Pro ( silicon chip)

Tags: installation, homebrew, sqlplus

I have been searching in internet for best way to install sqlplus in MacOs apple silicon chip ( arm bases processor).
please guide me some easiest method to do that.

I saw that many article about installing sqlplus in x64 intel based processor but not for the arm64 based processor.

Some more details about the system

Chip Apple M1 Pro
Mac OS version Mac OS Sonoma 14.3.1

Comment: So what did you try and what happened and what did you expect to happen instead? Why was a [web search](https://www.startpage.com/sp/search?query=sqlplus+install+macsos&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english) not an option?

Comment: @Robert Results of a web search revealed that ARM architecture is not natively supported for these Oracle packages, and Oracle does not provide an ARM architecture compatible Docker container for them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Oracle Instant Client files compatible with Apple silicon ARM-based Macs because Oracle Instant Client does not currently provide native support for this architecture, but you can install Rosetta 2 and UTM and run an [x86-based version of Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html) in an Ubuntu virtual machine on your Apple silicon Mac. Unfortunately graphics performance on ARM-based Macs would be substandard on this Ubuntu virtual machine.